# Search Method Failing

Tags: c, file, search, identifier

I'm trying to do a search Method in which checks 2 IDs which only store integer.

Firstly I have a database of customers. I input the Name,Surname,ID and Address after each other in this order and then these are immediately saved into the file

When the User inputs the ID card this calls this Search Method and checks through all the file  to see whether the ID is unique or not. If it is not, then it returns 0 otherwise it returns 1

Now the problem is this.
When I am inputting the ID, whether it is unique or not it keeps on going, but then when it outputs what I wrote it, for the NAME and SURNAME it shows only the first record I have stored there (like stuck in some kind of buffer), the ID and the address outputs normally.

The File is Also NOT Updated meaning, the save file did not occur.
Now when I Remove this method, the appending works normally, but I won't have access to the comparing of IDs.

Any suggestions why this is happening? and if possible any idea how I can fix it?
it's like whenever I'm doing this search method the whole file is getting started from the beginning and getting stuck there. I Tried using the method with boolean but still no avail. When I tried using it with Boolean instead of the line "if (customerID(scanf ("%d",&cCheck)) == 1)" I made it == TRUE, it was giving me an error that the output will
always be == FALSE because the data is not NULL.

and oh TRUE and FALSE are valid in my case as I have a typedef enum boolean in the common.h

The code is as follows [posting the whole file]:
The methods concerned are [ void addCustomer()] and [int customerID (int cCheck)
but I posted all as some of them are interconnecting.

EDIT!!! - The ID even if they are NOT unique, it is still Accepted...

```
/*
 * CustomerMainMenu.c
 * Author: DodoSerebro
 *
 * This class will output the Customer's Main Menu and re-directs to the
 * corresponding section
 *
 */
#include<io.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "..\Headers\common.h"
#include "..\Headers\customerManagement.h"

static FILE *cfp;
static customer c;
#define STRUCTSIZE sizeof (customer)


/** This is the Customers's Main Menu in which the various sections can be
 *  accessed from here
 */
boolean  customerMainMenu()
{



    int optionC;
    clrscr();

    copyright();


    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Customer's Main Menu *************\n \n \n");

    printf ("Press [1] to add a new Customer\n");
    printf ("Press [2] to edit a Customer\n");
    printf ("Press [3] to list all Customers\n");
    printf ("Press [4] to Show a Customer's last Order\n");
    printf ("Press [5] to go back to Main Menu\n\n\n");


    if (scanf ("%d",&optionC) == 1)
    {
        switch (optionC)
        {

        case 1:
        {
            clrscr();
            getchar();
            addCustomer();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            printf ("Edit a Customer\n");
            break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            clrscr();
            listCustomers();
            system ("PAUSE");
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            printf ("Customer's Last Order\n");
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            system ("PAUSE");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            if (optionC != 1 || optionC != 2 || optionC != 3 || optionC != 4 || optionC !=5)
            {
                clrscr();
                printf ("Invalid option!\n");
                system ("PAUSE");
                customerMainMenu();
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return TRUE;

}

/**
 *  This following method will append a customer to the
 *  database at the end of the file
 *
 *  */

void addCustomer ()
{
    char ch;
    copyright();

    printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Add Client **********\n \n \n");

    if ((cfp = fopen ("customers.dat","a+b")) == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Can't open customers.dat file\n",stderr);
    }



    printf ("\tThis will add another customer to the the database\n");
    printf ("\tPress 'Y' to confirm or 'N' to return to the Client Main Menu\n\tWITHOUT adding a customer\n");
    ch = getchar();

    if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N')
    {
        customerMainMenu();
    }
    else if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        clrscr();
        printf ("\n\n\n\n\t\t    ************* Add Client **********\n \n \n");
        printf ("Please enter Name:\n");
        while (scanf ("%s", c.name) == 0 || cCheck(c.name,100) == FALSE);
        {

        }


        printf ("Please Enter Surname: \n");
        while (scanf ("%s",c.surname) == 0 && cCheck (c.surname,100) == FALSE);
        {

        }
        printf ("Please Enter ID Card, [NOTE! Only numbers are allowed!]\n");
        int cCheck;
        if (customerID(scanf ("%d",&cCheck)) == 1)
        {
            printf ("ID already Taken, Client exists!\n");
            printf ("Do you want to enter another ID? 'Y' for Yes and 'N' to return to Main Menu\n");
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y')
            {
                scanf ("%d",&cCheck);
                customerID(cCheck);
                c.ID = cCheck;
            }
            else
            {
                customerMainMenu();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            c.ID = cCheck;
        }


        getchar();

        printf ("Please Enter Address:\n");
        gets(c.address);


        fwrite (&c,STRUCTSIZE, 1, cfp);

        printf ("For Testing purposes:\n");
        printf (" %s\n %s\n %s\n %d\n", c.name, c.surname, c.address, c.ID);
        askAnother();


    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\nInvalid choice! Either Y or N is accepted\n");
        system ("PAUSE");
        getchar();
        clrscr();
        addCustomer();
    }
}

void listCustomers()
{

    if ((cfp = fopen ("customers.dat","rb")) == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Can't open customers.dat file\n",stderr);
        printf ("Returning to Customer Main Menu");
        system ("PAUSE");
        customerMainMenu();
    }

    rewind (cfp);
    while (fread (&c,STRUCTSIZE,1,cfp)==1)
    {
        printf ("Customer: %s %s ID: %d\n", c.surname, c.name, c.ID);
    }
    fclose (cfp);


}


void askAnother()
{
    printf ("Do you want to add another Customer?\n");
    printf ("Enter 'Y' for yes and 'N' to return to the Main Menu\n");

    char input;
    input = getchar();

    if (input == 'Y' || input == 'y')
    {
        getchar();
        addCustomer();
    }
    else if (input == 'N'|| input == 'n')
    {

        fclose (cfp);
        customerMainMenu();

    }
    else
    {

        printf ("Invalid Option! Only Y or N are allowed\n");
        system ("PAUSE");
        clrscr();
        askAnother();

    }

}


boolean cCheck(char *test, int max)
{
    int x;
    for (x =0; x<max; x++)
    {
        if (isdigit(test[x]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (x==max)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        x++;

    }
    return TRUE;
}

/**
 *  This method will compare the ID passed from the ID of the customer to check
 *  whether it is exists or not. If it exists it will output 1 otherwise it
 *  will output -1. This will make sure that the Person's ID is unique
 *
 */


int customerID (int cCheck)
{

    rewind (cfp);
    while (fread (&c,STRUCTSIZE,1,cfp)==1)
    {
        if (c.ID == cCheck)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

EDIT!!

Uploading Image to show what I mean if I'm not clear

(Notice how the name and surname differ from those Input)
!http://s017.radikal.ru/i443/1212/c8/1ea9bc56d980.jpg

The following shows what I have in the file
(only one file)
!http://s017.radikal.ru/i431/1212/49/2a0df6acf9ec.jpg

Comment: Now give me a line number where it fails, don't expect me to read through this mess.

Comment: 145 is where it STARTS to fail..
Then the SearchMethod starts at line 273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (customerID(scanf ("%d",&cCheck)) == 1)
```

Here, you are the return value of scanf() to function `customerID()` whereas you actually wanted to pass the scanned value `cCheck`.

You can separate the call to function and input reading as below:

```
   if(scanf ("%d",&cCheck) != 1) {
   // Input error handling
   }
   else if (customerID(cCheck) == 1) {
    ...
```

Another issue is, you have a function named `cCheck` and you also have a local variable named `cCheck`. Rename one of them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the methods now work but there is a small problem. After I'm adding the record, it's NOT appending to the file, meaning the save file is getting ignored